# Dell Edge Gateway cloud-light color?

Tags: dell, snap, ubuntu-core

The Dell Edge Gateway 3002 has a 'cloud-led'/'cloud-light' that can be controlled through GPIO pin 346 and this works perfectly fine. However I can only get it to switch on/off in *green*, while the power-led (that sits next to it) can also turn yellow and amber.

I was wondering if it is possible / if anyone got the cloud-led to show these alternative colors as well?

Thanks!

-- Paul

Answer (score 1):

The Cloud LED is a single colour LED, your only control is to set the line high or low.